# nHow to glue two $ in php

Tags: php

How can I glue two $ in php?

I need to this :

```
$direct_link_p1 = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'direct_link_p1');
$direct_link_p1 = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'direct_link_p2');
$direct_link_p1 = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'direct_link_p3');
.  
.  
.
$direct_link_p1 = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'direct_link_p39');
$direct_link_p1 = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'direct_link_p40');
```

I am trying to use for this.

Or how can i use $i in code?

```
for($i= 1 ; $i <= 40 ; $i++){
   $direct_link_p **$i** = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'direct_link_p **$i**' );
}
```

Comment: whats this `**$i**`

Comment: Use array instead of indexed variables.

Comment: unclear your question... add some more info

Comment: @AbdullaNilam I need to put $i right here!

Comment: @BilalAhmed Now you can see some more info.

Comment: @AlirezaDarvishi  i have add answer below with some output format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create dynamic variable in PHP like this

```
for($i = 0; $i <= 40; $i++) {
${'direct_link_p' . $i}=get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'direct_link_p'.$i.' );

}
```

you can see the [OUTPUT](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a336d4ad7275e7fa314f9a574ddbc2fedfc67a05)

Answer (score 0):

It should work

```
for ($i = 0; $i <= 40; $i++) {
    ${'direct_link_p' . $i} = $i;
}

echo $direct_link_p1; // 1 
echo $direct_link_p2; // 2
```

But as I wrote in my comment, indexed variables (var1, var2, ...) is the right way to hell. Use array instead.